# Как заставить lampp создавать папки с разрешением 777

Tags: php, ubuntu, permissions, copy, lampp

Есть Ubuntu 20.4, Lampp.
Нужно перенести файлы из одной папки в другую, которая создается динамически с именем, указанным пользователем.
Создаю папки (php) mkdir($destination, 0777, true), по итогу разрешение 411 (owner daemon). Принудительно пишу chmod($destination,777), не помогает. Ну и раз папка без доступа то получаю ошибку при выполнении команды copy($source.$file, $destination.$file).
Новые папки пробовал и в htdocs и home/user - результат одинаковый. Куда копать ?

Comment: Во-первых, 0777 и 777 это разные вещи. Во-вторых, такие права это зло и делать так категорически не надо. В-третьих, если вы всё равно хотите творить зло, то проверьте umask

Comment: Я только начал изучать Ubuntu. В примерах указано mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700), так и делал. Я не принципиально хочу сделать разрешение 777, подскажите как правильно ? Мне нужно перекинуть файлы из общей папки (в которой они затрутся следующим тестом) в новую, просто для сохранения.

Comment: На самом деле же открывать все права на root папку нельзя...достаточно опять под root зайти и копировать что угодно и куда угодно